# Stream multiple files into a readable object in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

I have a function which processes binary data from a file using `file.read(len)` method. However, my file is huge and is cut into many smaller files 50 MBytes each. Is there some wrapper class that feeds many files into a buffered stream, and provides a read() method?

Class `fileinput.FileInput` can do such a thing, but it supports only line-by-line reading (method `readline()` with no arguments) and does not have `read(len)` with specifying number of bytes to read.

Comment: Are you looking for something inside the standard library? It shouldn't be too difficult to write this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with anything in the standard library that performs that function, so, in case there is none:

```
try:
    from cStringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from StringIO import StringIO

class ConcatenatedFiles( object ):
    def __init__(self, file_objects):
        self.fds= list(reversed(file_objects))

    def read( self, size=None ):
        remaining= size
        data= StringIO()
        while self.fds and (remaining>0 or remaining is None):
            data_read= self.fds[-1].read(remaining or -1)
            if len(data_read)<remaining or remaining is None: #exhausted file
                self.fds.pop()
            if not remaining is None:
                remaining-=len(data_read)
            data.write(data_read)
        return data.getvalue()
```

Comment: That works. Why do you use StringIO instead of just string for "data"?

Comment: @xivaxy Because, depending on the number of file objects and the size of the files, string concatenation would be inefficient. If you plan to use this in a small number of small files, you can use strings instead. See [this article](http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/) for details.

Comment: @goncalopp Note that that article is 10 years old. Things are surely changed in current versions of python (though I believe using `StringIO` and `join` are still the fastest methods).

Answer (score 6):

Instead of converting the list of streams into a generator - as some of the other answers do - you can chain the streams together and then use the file interface:

```python
def chain_streams(streams, buffer_size=io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE):
    """
    Chain an iterable of streams together into a single buffered stream.
    Usage:
        def generate_open_file_streams():
            for file in filenames:
                yield open(file, 'rb')
        f = chain_streams(generate_open_file_streams())
        f.read()
    """

    class ChainStream(io.RawIOBase):
        def __init__(self):
            self.leftover = b''
            self.stream_iter = iter(streams)
            try:
                self.stream = next(self.stream_iter)
            except StopIteration:
                self.stream = None

        def readable(self):
            return True

        def _read_next_chunk(self, max_length):
            # Return 0 or more bytes from the current stream, first returning all
            # leftover bytes. If the stream is closed returns b''
            if self.leftover:
                return self.leftover
            elif self.stream is not None:
                return self.stream.read(max_length)
            else:
                return b''

        def readinto(self, b):
            buffer_length = len(b)
            chunk = self._read_next_chunk(buffer_length)
            while len(chunk) == 0:
                # move to next stream
                if self.stream is not None:
                    self.stream.close()
                try:
                    self.stream = next(self.stream_iter)
                    chunk = self._read_next_chunk(buffer_length)
                except StopIteration:
                    # No more streams to chain together
                    self.stream = None
                    return 0  # indicate EOF
            output, self.leftover = chunk[:buffer_length], chunk[buffer_length:]
            b[:len(output)] = output
            return len(output)

    return io.BufferedReader(ChainStream(), buffer_size=buffer_size)
```

Then use it as any other file/stream:

```
f = chain_streams(open_files_or_chunks)
f.read(len)
```

Comment: It seems like with the way this is written, `self.leftover` will never be used, since `len(chunk) <= buffer_length` will always be true.

Comment: Looking at this again, I agree my code was being overly defensive and could be simplified.

Answer (score 5):

It's quite easy to concatenate iterables with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain

def read_by_chunks(file_objects, block_size=1024):
    readers = (iter(lambda f=f: f.read(block_size), '') for f in file_objects)
    return chain.from_iterable(readers)
```

You can then do:

```
for chunk in read_by_chunks([f1, f2, f3, f4], 4096):
    handle(chunk)
```

To process the files in sequence while reading it by chunks of `4096` bytes.

If you need to provide an object with a `read` method because some other function expects that you can write a very simple wrapper:

```
class ConcatFiles(object):
    def __init__(self, files, block_size):
        self._reader = read_by_chunks(files, block_size)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self._reader

    def read(self):
        return next(self._reader, '')
```

This however only uses a fixed block size. It's possible to support the `block_size` parameter for the `read` by doing something like:

```
def read(self, block_size=None):
    block_size = block_size or self._block_size
    total_read = 0
    chunks = []

    for chunk in self._reader:
        chunks.append(chunk)
        total_read += len(chunk)
        if total_read > block_size:
            contents = ''.join(chunks)
            self._reader = chain([contents[block_size:]], self._reader)
            return contents[:block_size]
    return ''.join(chunks)
```

Note: if you are reading in binary mode you should replace the empty strings `''` in the code with empty bytes `b''`.

Comment: This solution only works correctly if the file sizes are exact multiples of the chunk size.

Comment: @mahkitah Why do you think so? The iteration yields `block_size` chunks. But notice that when the `_reader` is consumed, the loop is skipped and you end up in `''.join(chunks)`. Also `read_by_chunks` will also return all contents even if the last bit is not of exact size.

Comment: @mahkitah E.g. `f1 = StringIO("a"*13); f2 = StringIO("b"7); f3 = StringIO("c"*4); c = ConcatFiles([f1,f2,f3], block_size=5)` and if you do `c.read()` multiple times you get `aaaaa`, `aaaaa`, `aaabb`, `bbbbb`, `cccc` and then empty string, which is correct. Here you can see that all the files have sizes not multiple of chunk size and even the total size is not a multiple

Comment: It only works like that when you use the wrapper and with the modified read method. The statement that you can use the `read_by_chunks` generator "_To process the files in sequence while reading it by chunks of `block_size` bytes._" is not true. When the generator reaches the end of each file it will yield whatever size is left.

Comment: @mahkitah **ALL** solutions work like that. Otherwise you either 1) drop the last chunk or 2) Add random data at the end to pad the chunk.  Look at all languages/libraries out there, if they have a "read by chunk" thing that works on a finite file the last chunk can be shorter. This is also true, for exaple, for S3 multipart API where the chunks must be at least a certain size but the last chunk can be shorter.

Comment: I understand that's how it works, but the answer states that `read_by_chunks` reads the sequence in chunks of 4096 bytes. And it doesn't do that. Not just for the very last chunk but also for intermediate chunks where it encounters the end of files. And yes, that is the logical outcome of how the parts work, but it still makes the statement wrong.

Comment: If somebody said to you: "I got this generator, it will take a bunch of file objects and read them in chunks of x bytes." You would expect that generator to yield x sized chunks up until the very last chunk, which could be smaller or padded. You wouldn't expect that generator to yield smaller chunks intermediately.

Comment: @mahkitah Yes and it fact it **doesn't**. Have you seen my comment with 3 example files? You can see that `ConcatFiles` only yields the last chunk shorter than 5.

Comment: I'm not talking about `ConcatFiles`. I'm talking about `read_by_chunks` and how its description gives false expectations. It says that `read_by_chunks` will read the files in chunks of 4096 bytes, but it will also read smaller chunks and not just the very last one.

Answer (score 0):

Another method would be to use a generator:

```
def read_iter(streams, block_size=1024):
    for stream in streams:
        for chunk in stream.read(block_size):
            yield chunk

# open file handles
file1 = open('f1.txt', 'r')
file2 = open('f2.txt', 'r')
fileOut = open('out.txt', 'w')

# concatenate files 1 & 2
for chunk in read_iter([file1, file2]):
    # process chunk (in this case, just concatenate to output)
    fileOut.write(chunk)

# close files
file1.close()
file2.close()
fileOut.close()
```

This shouldn't consume any memory beyond that required by the base script, and the chunk size; it's passing each chunk straight from one file reader, to the writer of another, then repeating until all streams are complete.

If you need this behaviour in a class, this could easily be build into a container class, as Bakuriu describes.