# How to read a sequence of files as one file (fileinput lacks read)?

Tags: python, io

I need to read a sequence of files and `fileinput` seemed just what was needed but then I realized it lacks a `read` method.

1. What is the canonical way (if any) to do this? (Explicit catenation will be wasteful.)
2. Is there a known technical or security reason that `fileinput` does not support `read`?

[This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33061307/fileinput-as-line-versus-fileinput-as-string) is not a duplicate.

Comment: What do you want to do with the data you `read`? If you want a single string, then just use e.g. `''.join(x for x in f)` on the fileinput object. Or do `list(f)` which is equivalent to `readlines()`

Comment: [`fileimput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput) lacks a `read()` because it "implements a helper class and functions to quickly write a loop over standard input or a list of files" — note the "write a loop". Also, because it supports multiple input files, reading the contents of one or all of them into memory at once was almost certainly not a design objective (and it would have rendered many of its methods — like `filename()` and `lineno()` — meaningless).

Comment: @match I want to pass it to another application, which expects a file-like object. (E.g., it may call `read` on it.)

Comment: something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528278/stream-multiple-files-into-a-readable-object-in-python maybe?

Comment: @KennyOstrom Good link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they're going to all be read into memory at once, you can make use of the [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) class

```
import io


class Filelike:
    def __init__(self, filenames):
        self.data = io.StringIO()
        for filename in filenames:
            with open(filename) as file:
                self.data.write(file.read())

        self.data.seek(0)  # Rewind.

    def read(self):
        return self.data.getvalue()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    filenames = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', ...]
    filelike = Filelike(filenames)

    # process lines
    for line in filelike.read().splitlines():
        print(repr(line))
```